# E-mail Forwarding Server

Tags: email, mail-server

I am looking for an e-mail server/client that does the following:

1. Runs as an e-mail server (POP3, IMAP, Exchange, etc) *for an isolated network*
2. Retrieves e-mail *from the isolated network*
3. Resend retrieved e-mail via another account (SMTP, IMAP, Exchange, etc) *to the main network*

The isolated network cannot directly access (or authenticate on) the regular mail server.  I want to put a small mail-server on the regular network which collects e-mail and sends to the regular mail server.

When an e-mail is received, the e-mail server (*forwarder, relay, gateway, etc*) should resend that message via a different e-mail account.

What would this be called? (ie: an e-mail forwarder, an e-mail relay, an e-mail proxy, e-mail gateway, etc)

NOTE: I'm not asking for specific product recommendations, only the correct terminology.

Comment: Pretty much any e-mail service will support email forwarding.  There isn't a "term" for it besides e-mail forwarding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is for a single user, this is just a fancy configuration for a regular old Mail User Agent (MUA), known to humans as a mail program like Outlook or Mail.app.  Fire it up, configure some rules (forward new mail to account, etc) and leave it running.

Based on comments, this is for all users, so you'd probably need to use Exchange Server with server-side forward rules for each user (assuming Windows server platform) or sendmail+.forward files for a UN*X platform, or one of several other alternatives for either.  The concept is the same though, a mail server (Mail Transport Agent / MTA) with a fancy configuration.

Comment: The end clients cannot access the regular mail server directly.  I essentially want to bounce e-mails across a mini-mail server on the network.

Comment: Updated answer... is that helpful?